# What is the solution of multi table ACID transaction in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I was following [this link to use a batch transaction without using BATCH keyword](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e#.ox7ikk2yr).

```
 Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
.addContactPoint(“127.0.0.1")
.build();
Session session = cluster.newSession();
//Save off the prepared statement you're going to use
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(“INSERT INTO tester.users (userID, firstName, lastName) VALUES (?,?,?)”);
//
List<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<ResultSetFuture>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
 //please bind with whatever actually useful data you're importing
 BoundStatement bind = statement.bind(i, “John”, “Tester”);
 ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(bind);
 futures.add(resultSetFuture);
}
//not returning anything useful but makes sure everything has completed before you exit the thread.
for(ResultSetFuture future: futures){
 future.getUninterruptibly();
}
cluster.close();
```

My question is with the given approach is it possible to INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE data **from different table** and if any of those fail all should be failed by maintaining the same performance (as described in the link).

With this approach what i tried, i was trying to insert, delete data from different table and one query got failed so all previous query was executed and updated the db.

With `BATCH` I can see that if any statement get failed all statement will be failed. But using `BATCH` on different table is anti-pattern so what is the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

> With BATCH I can see that if any statement get failed all statement will be failed.

Wrong, the guarantee of LOGGED BATCH is: if some statements in the batch fail, they will be retried until the succeed.

> But using BATCH on different table is anti-pattern so what is the solution ?

ACID transaction is not possible with Cassandra, it would require some sort of **global lock** or **global coordination** and be prohibitive performance-wise.

However, if you don't care about the performance cost, you can implement your self a global lock/lease system using **Light Weight Transaction** primitives as described [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/consensus-on-cassandra)

But be ready to face poor performance

Comment: in the gicen link only about LWT is mentioned not about  global lock or global coordination